# One word, preferably short, that describe "quantity limited"

Tags: single-word-requests

I run an e-commerce site and I want a word or very short phrase that convey the meaning of quantity limited that's easy to understand and also convey a sense of urgency.

This word or phrase will display over the product image.

However, I cannot display actual number quantities due to site performance reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it advertises a product.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you mean the example I showed advertises a product?

Comment: Only a few left

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was trying to clarify with the example image, did not intend to advertise anything.

Comment: I've occasionally seen the description on a website, 'When it's gone, it's gone' (also abbreviated to WIGIG), implying that a particular commodity either has limited availability or will not be restocked by the supplier.

Comment: I was using 'question' synecdochally for the entire OP. 'Only while stocks last' is another possibility. I am personally put off by such transparent sales techniques; I usually find that the better quality products have annoyingly sold out without warning.

Comment: I just checked, and I definitely don't see anything that says that questions about advertising language are "off-topic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can add:

> *last item* --- *last items* ---*last few items*

to the product image to inform potential clients that only one or just a few pieces of that specific product are left.

Comment: Last item would indicate 1 left in stock.  I want the message to show when stock is low (10 or less).

Comment: 'Last items' would work in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably choose *scarce* or *scant*.

From [Merriam Webster online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/),

> [**Scarce**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scarce)
>
> very small in amount or number : not plentiful

and

> [**Scant**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scant)
>
> very small in size or amount

Answer (score 2):

Elliot's "scarce" fits your criteria quite nicely, but I will also offer an alternative.

For a value labeled "Availability"  you could display, "Available", "Limited", "None"

For more of a sense of urgency you might replace "Limited" with "Hurry"